# Eclipse move the cursor left/right/up/down without using arrow keys

Tags: eclipse, text, editing

I'm very lazy and hate that I have to move my right hand to the arrow keys or mouse every 5 seconds to move the cursor around and edit text. Is there a way I can keep my hands in typing position and move the cursor around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change these settings in the specific **preferences** window:

**windows -> preferences-> general-> keys.**

There you can find this associations:

1. line up
2. line down
3. next column
4. previous column.

in binding, and press your buttons. After that you can select which keystroke to assign to:

[image]

for example:

1. alt+j <- colum.
2. alt+i up line.
3. alt+k down line.
4. alt+l -> colum.

Comment: I didn't realize it's called "Next Column/Previous Column" and you saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to use vim key binds as k – navigate upwards; j – navigate downwards ;l – navigate right side; h – navigate left side...this will help if later plan to switch to vim